# NZEC error in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

this is a simple piece of code which is suppose to read n numbers and suppose to print how many numbers out of these n numbers are divisible by k

```
n=int(raw_input())
k=int(raw_input())
ans=0
while n > 0:
  t=int(raw_input())
  if(t%k == 0):
    ans = ans + 1
  n = n - 1
print ans
```

I got a NZEC error for this on codechef. Can someone point out where does the issue lie? This NZEC error has bothered me a lot since last week. I am new to python and have searched a lot on internet but could not find anything concrete. I got the answer that NZEC error occurs when the stack size goes beyond limit. But what is the issue with my this code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suppose the codechef question is [this one](http://www.codechef.com/problems/INTEST). You should take in account that the value of n and k are around **10^7**, which could be a problem with your program.

Also, n and k are on the same line. You are using **raw_input** twice, so you are reading two lines. This can be solved by using:

```
n, k = raw_input().split(" ")
n = int(n)
k = int(k)
```

If that won't help, you could try looping over an **[xrange](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#xrange)** instead, or using a different algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

codechef would show you an NZEC when your code throws an exception. There are many possible reasons for the occurrence of this error, including but not limited to unsafe input handling, operating on non-existent/incorrect data, division by zero.

In your case, the problem can be solved as mentioned by Reshure. While handling other cases is going to be code specific, we can program in a way to avoid NZECs caused due to unsafe input handling. The idea is to read the input at once and tokenize it using whitespaces as delimiters.

```
import sys
tokenizedInput = sys.stdin.read().split()    # Delimit input by whitespaces
# Now iterate over tokenizedInput.
```

In your case, this would be as follows:

```
n, k = map(int, tokenizedInput[:2])
ans = 0
for _ in xrange(2, n):
    t = int(tokenizedInput[_])
    if t%k == 0:
        ans = ans + 1
print ans
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting NZEC error because when you enter space separated integers in python it is treated as a single string and not as two integers like in C,C++ and Java:
In your case, This should work:

```
n,k=map(int,raw_input().split())
```

Also in future remember, to input an integer array separated by spaces in python is:

```
a=map(int,raw_input().split())
```

Answer (score 0):

For pyth-3.4

```
n,k=[int(x) for x in input().split()]
count=0
while n>0:
    n-=1
    tmp=int(input())
    if tmp%k==0:
        count+=1
print (count)
```

Answer (score 0):

PUT TRY AND EXCEPT I DID THIS IN MY CODECHEF CODE AND IT'S WORKS

```py
try: 
    n , k = map(int , input().split())
    ans=0
    while n > 0:
        t=int(input())
        if(t%k == 0):
            ans = ans + 1
        n = n - 1
        print(ans) 
except:
    pass
```

Comment: Suppressing all exceptions like this is usually a very bad idea, as it can cover up real errors in your code without you knowing. Instead, you should usually debug your code and fix whatever is causing the errors. If some exceptions might get raised in the normal course of operations, consider catching those specific exceptions types, rather than catching everything with a bare `except`. Or use `except Exception as e` and log the details you can get from the exception object `e` before suppressing it (by not re-raising).

Comment: Buddy, it's only for "CODECHEF" once you complete your code and if at the time of submission on CODECHEF you face error than it's usefull