# python run time error (NZEC)

Tags: python

```
initial_bal = int( input("enter initial balance"))
withdraw_money = int( input("enter balance to withdraw"))
f = 0
if withdraw_money % 5 == 0 :
    if ( withdraw_money + 0.5 ) <= initial_bal:
        f = 1

if f == 1:
    account_bal = initial_bal - ( withdraw_money + 0.5 )
    print ("remaining balance : " , account_bal)
else :
    print(initial_bal)
```

---

when i submitted above written code to codechef , it threw runtime error(NZEC). Its working fine on my machine.
Can anyone tell , where is the error in my code?

Comment: This is Python 3.x code, did you select Python 3 from the list?

Comment: https://github.com/SavinaRoja/PyUserInput or https://fedorahosted.org/dogtail/ would be to prefer.

Comment: see here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9444503/nzec-error-in-python?rq=1

Comment: PiyusG i tried the solution given in the above link , but unfortunately error is same.

Comment: Please paste the problem link ...

Comment: http://www.codechef.com/problems/HS08TEST

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you don't have to print "enter initial balance" like stuff . You just have to print what's given in the test cases . Just print what's given in the test case .. nothing else... 
This is the actual code in python

```
class Main:

    s=raw_input()
    s=s.split(" ")
    x=float(s[0])
    y=float(s[1])
    if(x%5==0 and x+0.50<=y):
        p=y-x-0.50
        print("%.2f"%p)
    else:
        print("%.2f"%y)
```