# NZEC error in a simple Python code

Tags: python

This is similar to the question [NZEC error in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9444503/nzec-error-in-python) which has already been answered. However the approved answer does not work for me.

I tried doing the problem on Codechef (http://goo.gl/cHYm4W) using the following code:

```
x, y = raw_input().split(" ")
x = int(x)
y = float(y)

if x%5 == 0 and y-x-0.5 >= 0:
    y = y-x-0.5

print "%0.2f" % y
```

This gives me an NZEC error. But if i change it to

```
user_input = raw_input().split()
x = int(user_input[0])
y = float(user_input[1])

if x%5 == 0 and y-x-0.5 >= 0:
    y = y-x-0.5

print "%0.2f" % y
```

the code works alright. Can anyone please explain why the first approach isn't working?

Answer (score 10):

When you tried to do raw_input().split(" ") , it will given nzec error because when problem setter tried to upload the I/O test cases they usually left the space at the end. For Example 
if you have the input like this ..

1

3 2

Then after 3 and 2 you have some space left after 2, which led to nzec error in python.
So remember that instead of using split(" ") , use split() . The problems remain with the setter who uploaded the input test case and not with the code logic.